# Installing Eigen using cmake on Windows with MSVC: Why do I get: "Test EIGEN_COMPILER_SUPPORT_CPP11 - Failed"?

Tags: visual-c++, cmake, eigen, eigen3

I tried to install Eigen 3.4 by running cmake on the x64 Native Tools Command Prompt for VS2022 on a Windows machine:

```
c:\local\eigenbuild>cmake ..\eigen  
Building for: Visual Studio 17 2022  
Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.19041.0 to target Windows 10.0.22621.  
The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.36.32537.0  
The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.36.32537.0 
Detecting C compiler ABI info  
Detecting C compiler ABI info - done  
Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/VC/Tools  /MSVC/14.36.32532/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe - skipped  
Detecting C compile features  
Detecting C compile features - done 
Detecting CXX compiler ABI info  
Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done  
Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/VC/Tools  /MSVC/14.36.32532/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe - skipped  
Detecting CXX compile features  
Detecting CXX compile features - done  
Performing Test EIGEN_COMPILER_SUPPORT_CPP11  
Performing Test EIGEN_COMPILER_SUPPORT_CPP11 - Failed  
Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORT_std=cpp03  
Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORT_std=cpp03 - Failed`
.
.
.
skip snippet C:/local/eigen/doc/snippets/Array_initializer_list_23_cxx11.cpp because compiler does not support C++11
.
.
```

To my surprise, the tests for CPP11 and even for CPP03 failed.
How is this possible? What consequences does this have for the installation (using 'c:\local\eigenbuild>cmake --install . '?)

Comment: If by "latest stable version" you mean Eigen 3.4, then your case is already described in [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71876437/cmake-error-compiler-does-not-support-c11-when-configuring-eigen-with-visual) and its comments. You could try master revision of Eigen.

Comment: Thank your for hinting me to the other question, that I missed to find myself. I replaced "latest stable version" by "Eigen 3.4".